# Overlay Line on chart.js Graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I was wondering if it was possible to overlay a line ontop of a chart.js graph, such as a line graph ? For example, on the x axis a horizontal line would be drawn at value 20 across the graph

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created something called an overlay chart that i have added to my fork of chart.js (https://github.com/leighquince/Chart.js) that could be used in this situation. it works in the same was as a line or bar chart, only difference is you declare an extra property called `type` that can either be `'line'` or `'bar'`. Then just call `new Chart(ctx).Overlay(data)`.

So for your example you could just have your bar chart and then provided another data set (with some better colors than i have used) to show the line.

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    //new option, barline will default to bar as that what is used to create the scale
    type: "line",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)",
    pointColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    datasetFill:false,
    data: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
  }, {
    label: "My First dataset",
    //new option, barline will default to bar as that what is used to create the scale
    type: "bar",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,20,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,20,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,20,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [32, 25, 33, 88, 12, 92, 33]
  }]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx).Overlay(data, {
  responsive: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/leighquince/Chart.js/master/Chart.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 6):

I needed something similar, but instead of a line *graph* I needed like a real overlay line that was flat.

Just extended the chart like so:

```
    Chart.types.Bar.extend({
        name: 'BarOverlay',
        draw: function (ease) {
            Chart.types.Bar.prototype.draw.apply(this);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)';
            ctx.moveTo(35, this.scale.calculateY(100));
            ctx.lineTo(this.scale.calculateX(this.datasets[0].bars.length), this.scale.calculateY(100));
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    });
```

Mine is hard-coded to draw a line at the "100" mark (in this case, where we were looking at having a target of 100%).

And call it like so:

```
new Chart(ctx).BarOverlay(data, options);
```

I also found Quince's code out of date and not compatible with the 1.0.2 Chart.js code somehow (rendering went all sideways).

Answer (score 2):

StrangeWill's answer was excellent as a foundation but I needed data-driven vertical lines on a bar graph so modified it as follows:

First I added a property to the options array (adding another dataset is perhaps cleaner but I would have had to tell ChartJS to ignore it), where each option is a data value index that I want to highlight, roughly as follows:

```
ChartDefaults.verticalOverlayAtBar = [itemOne, itemTwo]
...
var HistoryChart = new Chart(ctx).BarOverlay(ChartData, ChartDefaults);
```

I then modified StrangeWill's code, extending it to iterate the array of items from above and draw vertical lines on the indicated bar.

```
Chart.types.Bar.extend({
    name: 'BarOverlay',
    draw: function (ease) {

        // First draw the main chart
        Chart.types.Bar.prototype.draw.apply(this);

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        var barWidth = this.scale.calculateBarWidth(this.datasets.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < this.options.verticalOverlayAtBar.length; ++i) {

            var overlayBar = this.options.verticalOverlayAtBar[i];

            // I'm hard-coding this to only work with the first dataset, and using a Y value that I know is maximum
            var x = this.scale.calculateBarX(this.datasets.length, 0, overlayBar);
            var y = this.scale.calculateY(2000);

            var bar_base = this.scale.endPoint

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)';
            ctx.moveTo(x, bar_base);
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.closePath();
    }
});
```

It's not perfect as I'm not familiar with the internals ChartJs code, in particular my lines were 2 bars off although my suspicion is that that's a fencepost error in the data array rather than the chart calculations.  However, hopefully it's a useful step forwards for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

There's https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation (via https://github.com/chartjs/awesome, "A curated list of awesome things related to Chart.js"):

> This plugin draws lines, boxes, points, labels, polygons and ellipses on the chart area.

> Annotations work with line, bar, scatter and bubble charts that use linear, logarithmic, time, or category scales.

BUT you can't have extra axes:

> Annotations will not work on any chart that does not have **exactly two axes**, including pie, radar, and polar area charts.