# Overlay Average Line on bar chart using angular-chart.js (chart.js)

Tags: angularjs, charts, angular-chart

I know there is way to to overlay 2 graph together (explained in this post: [Overlay Line on chart.js Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076525/overlay-line-on-chart-js-graph))

The `Overlay` of Chart.js method doesn't seem to be supported in the angular-chart.js library.

Is there any way to add this feature to the library without modifying the actual angular-chart.js file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom types as per the [stacked bar chart example](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/blob/master/examples/stacked-bars.html), however the `Overlay` chart seems to be via a fork of Chart.js itself so not sure how that would work.